# How does gdb select "current thread"?

Tags: multithreading, gdb

When `gdb` controls the program, it will select a thread as "current thread".

For example, use `gdb` to debug core dump file, the corrupt thread will be the "current thread":

```
# gdb -q program core_program_0_0_1402630731_27929
 (gdb) bt
 #0  0xfefb2d50 in strlen () from /lib/libc.so.1
 #1  0xff01f4a0 in _ndoprnt () from /lib/libc.so.1
 #2  0xff021cac in vsprintf () from /lib/libc.so.1
 ......
 #9  0xff04aee8 in _lwp_start () from /lib/libc.so.1
```

But if the program is running, when the `gdb` attach it, how does it select the "current thread"? I have done a test, and find it uses the main thread as the "current thread".

Does `gdb` always choose main thread as the "current thread"? I have searched in the [gdb manual](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Threads.html), but unfortunately, there is no answer about it.

Could any one give some comments on this issue?

Answer (score 2):

`gdb` keeps the current thread info in this variable:

```
/* Collected pid, tid, etc. of the debugged inferior.  When there's
   no inferior, ptid_get_pid (inferior_ptid) will be 0.  */

extern ptid_t inferior_ptid;
```

I think it might be platform dependent how `gdb` chooses the current thread after attaching to a process. Take for example `gdb` on Linux. On Linux PID of a process is equal to PID of its main thread.  So `gdb` uses PID of a process you want to attach to as ID of the current thread of the process:

This is code from `gdb` where the current thread ID is set:

```
static void
linux_nat_attach (struct target_ops *ops, char *args, int from_tty)
{
  struct lwp_info *lp;
  int status;
  ptid_t ptid;
  volatile struct gdb_exception ex;

  /* Make sure we report all signals during attach.  */
  linux_nat_pass_signals (0, NULL);

  TRY_CATCH (ex, RETURN_MASK_ERROR)
    {
      linux_ops->to_attach (ops, args, from_tty);
    }

   /* some code is skipped */

  /* The ptrace base target adds the main thread with (pid,0,0)
     format.  Decorate it with lwp info.  */
  ptid = BUILD_LWP (GET_PID (inferior_ptid), GET_PID (inferior_ptid));
  thread_change_ptid (inferior_ptid, ptid);
```

So it use `pid` of a process as value for LWP of the current thread. And this is backtrace where the current thread ID is set:

```
Hardware watchpoint 1: inferior_ptid

Old value = {pid = 11386, lwp = 0, tid = 0}
New value = {pid = 11386, lwp = 11386, tid = 0}
0x000000000057ba69 in infrun_thread_ptid_changed (old_ptid=..., new_ptid=...) at infrun.c:1592
1592        inferior_ptid = new_ptid;
(gdb) bt
#0  0x000000000057ba69 in infrun_thread_ptid_changed (old_ptid=..., new_ptid=...) at infrun.c:1592
#1  0x00000000005c87ca in observer_thread_ptid_changed_notification_stub (data=0x0, args_data=0x0) at observer.inc:728
#2  0x00000000005c8595 in generic_observer_notify (subject=<optimized out>, args=0x7fffffffdcc0) at observer.c:167
#3  0x00000000005c8c37 in observer_notify_thread_ptid_changed (old_ptid=..., new_ptid=...) at observer.inc:753
#4  0x000000000048b81b in linux_nat_attach (ops=0xb95220, args=0x7fffffffe3b3 "11386", from_tty=1) at linux-nat.c:1635
#5  0x00000000005b7879 in target_attach (args=0x7fffffffe3b3 "11386", from_tty=1) at target.c:3798
#6  0x000000000057a587 in attach_command (args=0x7fffffffe3b3 "11386", from_tty=1) at infcmd.c:2578
#7  0x00000000005919e7 in catch_command_errors (command=0x57a4f0 <attach_command>, arg=0x7fffffffe3b3 "11386", from_tty=1, mask=<optimized out>) at exceptions.c:573
#8  0x00000000005940d8 in captured_main (data=<optimized out>) at main.c:963
#9  0x0000000000591a94 in catch_errors (func=0x593330 <captured_main>, func_args=0x7fffffffdfd0, errstring=0x759429 "", mask=6) at exceptions.c:546
#10 0x0000000000593094 in gdb_main (args=<optimized out>) at main.c:1050
#11 0x0000000000457a76 in main (argc=<optimized out>, argv=0x0) at gdb.c:34
```

Answer (score 1):

http://sunsite.ualberta.ca/Documentation/Gnu/gdb-5.0/html_node/gdb_24.html

Gdb have the current thread set to the thread that generatesd the exception, breakpoint or was currently scheduled.

Comment: @user3737345: when I open the link, it displays "404 File not found.".  Could you open it?

Comment: Actually I didn't manage to find `was currently scheduled` on that page. I even didn't find `scheduled` on it. Besides, I wrote a test in which first thread lauches another thread and then the first thread goes to sleep (so it is not scheduled). However when I attach with gdb to the process the current thread is the first thread which actually sleeps.